# Single word for the animal action of bending down

Tags: single-word-requests, animals

I'm looking for a single word to describe the bending-down motion that animals such as camels or elephants do to allow riders/passengers to more easily mount them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Camels **kneel**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/kneel), which is defined as "To stoop down and rest on the knee or knees." <sup>1</sup>

#### Examples of Use:

*[Bârakh - בּרך](https://www.studylight.org/language-studies/hebrew-thoughts.html?article=551) ([Strong's #1288](https://www.studylight.org/lexicons/hebrew/01288.html)) To kneel, bless* from Hebrew Thoughts (2018© KJ Went)

> Genesis 24:11<sup>2</sup> records how Abraham's servant, in search of a bride for Isaac, brought his master's camels to a well frequented by local women and there יברך yabh'rêkh "he made his camels kneel down".
>
> The Arabic use of the verb also includes making one's camel kneel, an odd process of first bending one pair of knees, sending the rider forwards, then collapsing the back knees, sending the rider backwards, finally coming to rest with both knees folded underneath and the rider able to dismount. Indeed, as with Abraham's servant, the desert bedu virtually lived on his camel only dismounting to sleep, eat or drink, and the word for a pool of water where camels 'kneel' to drink, the discovery of which, in the desert, was a 'blessing', was called a בּרכה berêkhâh 'pool, pond'

The Gale Encyclopedia of Science's (©2014, 2017) [Elephant](http://science.jrank.org/pages/2417/Elephant-Limbs.html) entry shows us that **elephants *kneel* too**:

> Elephants kneel on their "wrists," stand upright on their back legs, sit on their haunches, and can be trained to balance on their front feet. The feet have thick, sponge-like pads with ridged soles which act as shock-absorbers and climbing boots, helping these sure-footed animals to ascend embankments and negotiate narrow pathways with amazing dexterity.

---

#### Footnotes:

<sup>1</sup> Definition extracted from [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=kneel&oldid=47682251), under the terms of the [CC-BY-SA 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) license.

<sup>2</sup> In the King James Version bible, [Genesis 24:11](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis+24%3A11&version=KJV) reads: "And he made his camels to kneel down without the city by a well of water at the time of the evening, even the time that women go out to draw water."